# Emulators can't load "libGLES_emulation" driver

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am in the process of setting up `FirebaseUI` using [Google's guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) but I suddenly got an error I can't seem to find a solution for. I'm pretty sure it has to do with my gradle, because I've tried commenting changes in my Java files, using my phone instead of an AVD, and other emulators to no avail. I've included what I got in the Run console, Manifest, and gradles. If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks!

---

**EDIT: For those with the same issue, I think I fixed it by updating Google Play services on the API Q emulator (you have to sign in to Google Play first), then I added the following to the app-level gradle:**

```
android {
     ...
     compileOptions {
         ...
         sourceCompatibility = 1.8
         targetCompatibility = 1.8
         ...
     }
     ...
}
```

**I don't know how it worked, but I hope it does for you too.**

---

**Run (conflicts only)**

```
...
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
...
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:4480): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=8377 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c119,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
...
W/xample.litloca: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection)
...
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
...
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
```

**Run (full)**

```
09/07 19:52:53: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API Q.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.litlocal/com.example.litlocal.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 14608 on device 'Pixel_2_API_Q [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/xample.litloca: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/xample.litloca: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:4449): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=8377 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c119,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/xample.litloca: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection)
W/xample.litloca: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdc721500, tid 14666
D/: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdc7124e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdc7124e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdc708f60)
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.litlocal, 1:175514927228:android:47ec351c4609ff5c6609f9
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 18202
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.litlocal
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
D/: createUnique: call
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdc721640, tid 14666
D/: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdc7124e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdc708f60)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/xample.litloca: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 16987(4410KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(224KB) LOS objects, 78% free, 1696KB/7840KB, paused 6.401ms total 59.038ms
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
V/FA: Session started, time: 27900964
D/FA: Setting user property (FE): _sid, 1567911177
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_session_id(_sid)=1567911177}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 27900309
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=8377598752693967695}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 6
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.litlocal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="LitLocal">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEventActivity"
            android:label="@string/create_event_activity_name"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SetEventLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/set_event_location_activity_name"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_activity_name"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Grade (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.litlocal"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "en"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        /*sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8*/
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.2.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v8:0.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    // Tentative for login
    //implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  Having similar issue, I'm using AWS and a parse server though

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
android {
     ...
     compileOptions {
         ...
         sourceCompatibility = 1.8
         targetCompatibility = 1.8
         ...
     }
     ...
}
```